# Can't connect to Oracle from Visual Studio with System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2017, provider

I'm trying to connect to Oracle 12.2.0 from Visual Studio 2017 using **System.Data.OracleClient** provider and get ORA-12638 error.

I can connect to database from sqldeveloper or using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client** provider.

My connection string is:
**name="ConnectionString"
            connectionString="DATA SOURCE=xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx/xx;PASSWORD=yyyy;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=yyyyy;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"**

I have System.Data.OracleClient in References. I change SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES to (NONE) in sqlnet.ora.

Any ideas what might be wrong or where should I start looking?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated for ages, you should not use it in new projects. For example Unicode is not supported by this provider.

Comment: I understand this, but it is not my application, I need just add some rdlc reports, but can't do it without working database connection

Comment: Your ConnectionString  is wrong. For basic example of ConnectionString see [Oracle Data Provider for .NET / ODP.NET connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/), for more details see [OracleConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: What is wrong with connection string? I can't see any problems, besides other developers have no problem with connection